# Assigning a filepath to a variable in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, file, filesystems, variable-assignment

I am trying to convert few camera-clicked images of handwritten Gujarati characters to the form of MNIST dataset as I intend to pass the Gujarati handwritten characters images to the MNIST deep learning model. And as part of that, I'm trying to assign a file path to a variable named "datadir". But when executing the below code in Ubuntu 16.04, the terminal throws the error which looks like this:
 File "gujaratinn.py", line 7
    datadir = /home/cryptoaniket256/Desktop/opencv-3.4.1/project/Resize
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

### Note that the name of the file is gujaratinn.py and all the camera-clicked images are stored in the Resize folder.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
import os
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

datadir = Path("/home/cryptoaniket256/Desktop/opencv- 
3.4.1/project/Resize")
fileToOpen = datadir/"practice.txt"
f = open(fileToOpen)
print(f.read())
```

Comment: Also do `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the script's directory instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you affecting datadir with a path you wrote on 2 rows in your code ?

Try to put line 7 and 8 on the same row or change the quotes like that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
import os
import cv2
from pathlib import Path

datadir = Path("""/home/cryptoaniket256/Desktop/opencv-3.4.1/project/Resize""")
fileToOpen = datadir/"practice.txt"
f = open(fileToOpen)
print(f.read())
```

Comment: Hello @NickNick! Actually, line number 7 and 8 are on the same line itself in the actual code.

Comment: Hurray! The change of quotes solution worked @NickNick! Thank You, buddy, for the help.